# Unable to Pass Data Between Interface Controllers

Tags: swift, watchkit

I'm having a problem passing a string to a new interface controller in my WatchKit app. The segue to the new interface controller is hooked up in the storyboard from the table row. Here is my code for the selection of a table row:

```
  var selectedElement: String!
  override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
    switch rowIndex{
    case 0:
        selectedElement = menuElements.objectAtIndex(0) as! String
    case 1:
        selectedElement = menuElements.objectAtIndex(1) as! String
    case 2:
        selectedElement = menuElements.objectAtIndex(2) as! String
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Then I am using this method to pass the selectedElement variable as the context:

```
  override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject? {
    return selectedElement
 }
```

In my SecondInterfaceController class, I am trying to use this code to display the context string in a label:

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
    label.setText(context as? String)
 }
```

This produces a blank label, and I also tried printing the context to the console, and it returned nil.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to display?

Comment: I am trying to display the string that is connected to a table view row in a label on a second interface controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass data between interface controllers you need add this method

```
pushControllerWithName:context:
```

Comment: Take a look at this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021186/passing-data-back-from-a-modal-view-in-watchkit

Comment: Also, here is an nice example which might help you - http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2272657&seqNum=3