# prepareForSegue equivalent in WatchKit

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, watchkit

I have an interface with 2 buttons, both of them call the same interface but with different information. On the traditional interface I use prepareForSegue, but I don't know what's the equivalent one on the WatchKit.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

In your storyboard you set an identifier in your segue:

[image]

and then you can use `contextForSegueWithIdentifier`:

```
- (id)contextForSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)segueIdentifier {
     if ([segueIdentifier isEqualToString:@"yourIdentifier"]) {
        return aDictionaryWithYourInformation;
     }
}
```

Or you can pass information with a context via code, with:

```
[self pushControllerWithName:@"YourViewController"
                     context:aDictionary];
```

This context is a dictionary and you have access to this dictionary in the `- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context`

Comment: Correct answer, similar Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021186/passing-data-back-from-a-modal-view-in-watchkit/46421098#46421098

Answer (score 11):

For segue navigation in Watchkit there are two methods in WKInterfaceController:

```
override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject? {
        return //your object
    }
```

and for tables

```
override func contextsForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> [AnyObject]? {
      return  //your object
    }
```

you can get the object you are passing in `func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?)` of the interface controller you are pushing

Answer (score 2):

In WatchKit, you can use this for calling WKInterfaceController:

```
[self pushControllerWithName:@"YourControlName"
          context:[self contextForSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourControlName"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

For tables it's the following:

```
override func contextForSegue(withIdentifier segueIdentifier: String, in table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> Any? {
     return  //your object
    }
```