# Custom Swift 2 Struct - Cannot subscript a value of type [ILT] on pushControllerWithName()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, watchkit

I am trying to pass my custom struct `ILT` through `pushControllerWithName()` so I can pass it to the next screen in my watchOS 2 app. `ILTList` is an array of `ILT` types, and the `pushControllerWithName()` is happening when the user taps on a row in the table, which has its' rows fed from `ILTList`.

ILTList is initialised with `var ILTList = [ILT]()`, and the ILT struct is as follows:

```
struct ILT {
    let homeworkID: Int
    let title: String
    let subject: String
    let teacher: String
    let teacherCode: String
    let studentID: Int
    let description: String
    let due: Double
    let status: String
    let hasAttachments: Bool
}
```

And this is where the tap occurs:

```
override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
    print(ILTList[rowIndex])
    let context:AnyObject = ILTList[rowIndex]
    self.pushControllerWithName("showILT", context: context)
}
```

With this code I get

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[ILT]'

When I change `context:AnyObject` to just `context` or `context:ILT`, it says:

> Cannot convert value of type 'ILT' to expected argument type
>   'AnyObject'?

What am I missing here?

Comment: try `let context:AnyObject = ILTList[rowIndex].title`

Comment: This works, however I need to pass every part of it - not just title

Comment: then u need to pass it in prepareForSegue

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695062/prepareforsegue-equivalent-in-watchkit

Comment: Thanks, I will use this. Still isn't clear to me why I can't pass an ILT object if it's AnyObject though? Or does that mean it can be any type of object **within** a dictionary?

Comment: i guess no, must be not only a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who really want to use `pushControllerWithName()`, I formed the following solution by converting my `ILT` variable type to a `Dictionary`.

```
override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
    // construct the dictionary
    let context = [
        "title":ILTList[rowIndex].title,
        "subject":ILTList[rowIndex].subject,
        "teacher":ILTList[rowIndex].teacher
    ]
    self.pushControllerWithName("showILT", context: context)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird error message. I think the problem might be that pushControllerWithName:context: takes a context of type AnyObject?, and structs can't be passed for that type. A dictionary works because it is a class-type object.